# How can I make the cam ignore the y axis while player jumps using Cinemachine in Unity2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-engine

Good day, I'm making a 2D platformer game and I'm trying to make to cam follow the player. But ignore the y-axis so when the player jumps the cam stays in positions instead of following the player.

Example (see asset pack demo): https://ansimuz.itch.io/gothicvania-church-pack

How can I do this using Cinemachine?

Comment: did you tried changing the cinemachine body to "Framing Transposer" then set Y deadzone to 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to override the camera's Y value in your camera controller script. This would be a very basic implementation:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject player;        //Public variable to store a reference to the player game object
public bool followY = false;

private Vector3 offset;            //Private variable to store the offset distance between the player and camera

// Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        //Calculate and store the offset value by getting the distance between the player's position and camera's position.
        offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
    }

// LateUpdate is called after Update each frame
    void LateUpdate () 
    {
        // Set the position of the camera's transform to be the same as the player's, but offset by the calculated offset distance.
        if(followY)
          {
          transform.position = player.transform.position + offset; // we should follow the player Y movements, so we copy the entire position vector
          }
        else
          {
          transform.position = new Vector3(player.transform.position.x, transform.position.y, player.transform.position.z) + offset; // we just copy the X and Z values
          }
    }
}
```

Attach this script to the camera and you can enable or disable the Y-axis movement by setting the boolean accordingly. In case you will never need this functionality, just keep the line in the else block.

I hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the dead zone height to 1 in the cinemachine camera component. Then try it out. It worked for me.